# Showing/hiding divs based on jPlayer time update

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I'm building a slide presentation with audio, using jPlayer. I want lines of text to appear based on the current time. Each line is wrapped in a div, hidden and given a class. I've added in and out attr to the divs. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer( {
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: "media/audio.mp3",
            oga: "media/audio.ogg"
        }).jPlayer("play");
    },
    supplied: "mp3, oga",
    swfPath: "js"
});

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, function(event) {
    currentTime = Math.floor(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime)

    var slidesdiv = $('#slides');

    // Hides all slides to start
    $(slidesdiv).children().addClass('starthidden');

    // stores the number of slides
    var numslides = $(slidesdiv).children().length;

    // adds slidexx class to each div
    $('#slides > div').addClass(function() {
        return 'slide' + $(this).index();
    });

    if (currentTime >= $('#slides > div').attr('in') && currentTime < $('#slides > div').attr('out')) {
        $('#slides > div').fadeIn("fast");
    } else {
        $('#slides > div').fadeOut("fast");
    }
});
});
</script>
```

and the html:

```
<div id="slides">
    <!-- Slide 1 -->
    <div in="1" out="3"><h2>Implications</h2></div>
    <div in="5" out="8">Implications have the form</div>
            etc..
</div>
```

I've gotten pretty close, and the whole #slides appears at 1sec, disappears at 3sec, but I need only the first div to come go, then move on to the next div and it's in/out times. Can anyone help?

Thanks, 
S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script might help you a bit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#slides").find("div").hide();

        var currentInOut = 0;
        var code = setInterval(function () {
            var currDiv = Number() == currentInOut;
            $.each($("#slides").find("div"), function () {
                if (Number($(this).attr("in")) <= currentInOut && Number($(this).attr("out")) >= currentInOut) {
                    $(this).show();
                    $(this).siblings().hide();
                }
            });
            currentInOut += 1;
            if (currentInOut >= Number($("#slides").find("div").last().attr("out"))) {
                clearInterval(code);
            }
        }, 1000);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ulhas Tuscano. I was able to learn enough from your code to figure it out! Thanks for the quick answer!